# I want to send multiple checkbox values from a form to process in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to send multiple checkbox values in a form to CodeIgniter for processing

View:

```html
    <input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" value="Milan" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" value="Rome" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" value="Detroit" />
```

Controller:

```php
    // Define email data
    $mailData = array(
        'name' => $formData['name'],
        'email' => $formData['email'],
        'cities' => $formData['cities[]']
    );

    // Mail content
    $mailContent = '
        <h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
        <p><b>Name: </b>'.$mailData['name'].'</p>
        <p><b>Email: </b>'.$mailData['email'].'</p>
        <p><b>Cities: </b>'.$mailData['cities'].'</p>'; //`I want display checkbox values in one line here`
```

How do I capture the value(s) of all of the checked boxes in CodeIgniter and display them in one line? (that I will send in an email)